# Progress bar for transferring files to iDevice on macOS 10.15

Tags: itunes, catalina

There used to be a progress bar in iTunes, when transferring files to iDevices (Apps with file sharing). However, with the new Finder interface on Catalina, no such progress bar can be found when copying those files.

Is there any way to check the progress? This is particularly annoying as transfer of large folders usually fails in the middle.

Comment: I am new to Catalina, but it is *crazy* to me that there is no way to monitor the progress of a large file transfer, or *even tell if it has begun*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reported this to Apple in August 2019 during Catalina beta; the issue is still present in release and yet to be fixed. FB7102998